# Is there any way I can make PyDrive remember authentication for a user?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I made a program using Python and PyDrive.
The program captures an image and uploads it to a folder on Google Drive.
This is the basic code for my authentication and upload:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file_image = drive.CreateFile({"parents":  [{"kind": "drive#fileLink","id": upload_folder_id}]})
file_image.SetContentFile(imageName) #Set the content to the taken image
file_image.Upload() # Upload it
```

Any time I run the program it wants to authenticate me. Is there any way to remember the authentication?

Comment: I don't think so, in the webinterface remember authentication is solved by cookies.

Comment: And is it possible to log in with a username, password combination from a config file? (So that way I only have to create that config file once)

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. Using Py 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Would a usage of `eval()` be okay??

Comment: Yes it's okay (but I've never used it)

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer. See in a minute

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm really interested in the solution

Answer (score 0):

In the webinterface of Google Drive, cookies are used to remember authification. I would recommend to read the login information from a config file and login each time you use the script. You may use `eval()` with that, but remember, `eval()` is evil :) (If the script is only used by you, it's okay).

Sample:

Create a file called `login.conf` (or similar) in the same folder your script is in. The put this in it:

```
{"user": "username", "pass": "password"}
```

Replace `"username"` and `"pasword"` with your real values, but keep the `"`. In your script, do it like this:

```
with open("login.conf", "r") as f:
    content = eval(f.read())

username = content["user"]
password = content["pass"]

# Now do login using these two variables
```

A more secure option would be the usage of `ConfigParser` (`configparser` in Python 3.x).

**EDIT:**

It looks like login to Google Drive requires afile called `client_secrets.json` in the directory of your script. If you have it, do login like this:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("credentials.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    gauth.Authorize()

gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("credentials.txt")

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Hope this helps (Ask, if something is not clear enough)!

Comment: Thank you! The other part what is not clear for me is that, how can I use this information to login to my Google Drive. How is it possible with PyDrive?

Comment: Ok. I've never used PyDrive, but the docs says, you need a file called `client_secrets.json`. Do you have it?

Comment: Yes, that's the file where I store my Google Drive api secret keys

Comment: Updated my answer, please try. The first code sample is not needed anymore, but useful for later projects using config files :)

Comment: Yes this is it, but now I need authorization every time I use the python app. (Thanks for the config code, that really helps :) )

Comment: If yes, you might accept my answer. If not, what is the problem now?

Comment: It's not solved because I have to authorize myself with my browser every time I run the app

Comment: Hey, I've found something else: try my edited code! This should require a webbrowser loging only at the first time and  when your password was changed!

Comment: I tried it and it authorizes once than again and than error: `Failed to find "code" in the query parameters of the redirect.
Try command-line authentication
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testDrive.py", line 10, in <module>
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 69, in _decorated
    code = decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydrive\auth.py", line 188, in LocalWebserverAuth
    raise AuthenticationError('No code found in redirect')
pydrive.auth.AuthenticationError: No code found in redirect`

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. I'll install the PyDrive package and do some test. Keep looking, if I'm updating my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for putting this much effort in it.